# CSS issues with dropdown in a nested table

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu

I'm trying to display a dropdown list correctly in a nested table.

I have the following problem:

- I need the table position to be *relative* in order to be correctly nested.
- I need `td` overflow to be set to *hidden* in order to hide long lines.
- However, when table position is *relative* and overflow is *hidden*, **the dropdown list is also partially hidden**. I would like to avoid that.

#### Edit:

- I also want my dropdown list be right aligned to the icon. The example at the bottom of this post is right aligned.

[image]

Here are some screenshots to illustrate the problem:

---

`position:relative` + `overflow:hidden`:

[image]

---

`position:absolute` + `overflow:hidden`:

[image]

---

`position:relative` + `overflow:visible`:

[image]

---

## Is there a way to display the nested tables and the dropdown list correctly?

---

```css
table {
  position:relative; /* <------- */
 font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
 color:#666;
 font-size:12px;
 text-shadow: 1px 1px 0px #fff; 
  background:#eaebec;
 margin:20px;
 border:black 1px solid; 
 border-radius:3px; 
  border-collapse: collapse;
 box-shadow: 0 1px 2px #d1d1d1;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  table-layout:fixed;
  width:400px;  
}

th, td {
    overflow:visible; /* <------- */
    z-index:100000;
    border: 1px solid black;    
    height:17px;
    word-wrap: break-word;   
    white-space: nowrap;   
}

.outerTable {
  width:450px;  
}

.context-icon {
    float:right;
    cursor:default;
    color: green;
    padding-right: 10px;
    padding-left: 10px;
}

.filter {        
     visibility: hidden;
     display: block;
     position: absolute;     
     background-color: #f9f9f9;
     box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
     padding: 2px 6px;          
     max-height: 0px;
     z-index: 1000;
     height:auto;
     transition: visibility 200ms, max-height 200ms ease-in-out;
     right:0px;
}

.filter-container {
  position:relative
}

.filter-open {
    display: block;
    max-height: 400px;
    visibility: visible;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<body>

<table class="outerTable">
<tbody>
<tr>
  <td>000000 00000000 0000000000 00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000</td>
  <td>1111111 11111 11111 111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111 </td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td colspan="2">
<table>
<thead>
  <tr>
    <th>first</th>    
    <th>
      second
      <span>
        <i class="context-icon fa fa-lg fa-filter">
        <span class="filter-container">
          <select multiple class="filter filter-open">
            <option>option1</option>
            <option>option2</option>
            <option>option3</option>        
            <option>option4</option>  
            <option>option5</option>  
          </select>
        </span>
        </i>
      </span>
    </th>
    <th>third</th>
  </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
  <tr>
    <td>XXXXX XXXXXX XXXXXXXXXX XXXXXXXXXXXXXX</td>
    <td>YYYYY YYYYYY YYYYYYYYYY YYYYYYYYYYYYYY</td>
    <td>ZZZZZ ZZZZZZ ZZZZZZZZZZ ZZZZZZZZZZZZZZ</td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>000000 00000000 0000000000 00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000</td>
  <td>1111111 11111 11111 111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111 </td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>000000 00000000 0000000000 00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000</td>
  <td>1111111 11111 11111 111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111 </td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>

</body>
```

Comment: Would `text-overflow` be of any help on the `th, td` CSS?

Comment: What about the z-index?

Comment: @tohood87 - text-overflow has effect only when overflow is hidden.

Comment: @PatrickKnudsen z-index did not have any effect, probably because a hidden element is not laid out at all.

Comment: @CBroe placing the dropdown list outside the table will make is harder to align it to the icon it is opened from (the 'filter' icon). I'm looking for a simpler solution - it feels I'm almost there, if only I could solve the text overflow issue when `position:relative` and `overflow:visible`.

Comment: Does .filter needs to be absolute or can it also be fixed? http://codepen.io/anon/pen/eZdXXa

Comment: @AmirGonnen - what about just having the outer table as position relative: `table.outerTable { position:relative; }`

Comment: @Goombah `.filter` cannot be fixed since it must be opened under the "filter" icon, not on a fixed position on the screen.

Comment: @Goombah fixed `.filter` works when table is naturally aligned left, but not when `right` is set to 0px, in order to right align the dropdown box. However, if I find a different way to right align the drop down box, this solution could work.

Comment: @Goombah another problem with `fixed` is that it won't scroll. The table can be scrolled down but the dropdown window will stay 'fixed'....

Comment: @tohood87 It didn't work for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems that setting overflow: hidden on the table isn't really needed, it's enough to set it on the *td*s. The dropdown is inside the *th* and won't be affected:

```css
.outerTable > tbody > tr > td {
    overflow: hidden;  
}
.outerTable > tbody > tr > td#special_td {
    overflow: visible;  
}

.innerTable td {
    overflow: hidden;  
}

table {
  position:relative; /* <------- */
 font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
 color:#666;
 font-size:12px;
 text-shadow: 1px 1px 0px #fff; 
  background:#eaebec;
 margin:20px;
 border:black 1px solid; 
 border-radius:3px; 
  border-collapse: collapse;
 box-shadow: 0 1px 2px #d1d1d1;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  table-layout:fixed;
  width:400px;  
}

th, td {
    overflow:visible; /* <------- */
    z-index:100000;
    border: 1px solid black;    
    height:17px;
    word-wrap: break-word;   
    white-space: nowrap;   
}

.outerTable {
  width:450px;  
}

.context-icon {
    float:right;
    cursor:default;
    color: green;
    padding-right: 10px;
    padding-left: 10px;
}

.filter {        
     visibility: hidden;
     display: block;
     position: absolute;     
     background-color: #f9f9f9;
     box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
     padding: 2px 6px;          
     max-height: 0px;
     z-index: 1000;
     height:auto;
     transition: visibility 200ms, max-height 200ms ease-in-out;
     right:0px;
}

.filter-container {
  position:relative
}

.filter-open {
    display: block;
    max-height: 400px;
    visibility: visible;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<body>

<table class="outerTable">
<tbody>
<tr>
  <td>000000 00000000 0000000000 00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000</td>
  <td>1111111 11111 11111 111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111 </td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td colspan="2" id="special_td">
<table class="innerTable">
<thead>
  <tr>
    <th>first</th>    
    <th>
      second
      <span>
        <i class="context-icon fa fa-lg fa-filter">
        <span class="filter-container">
          <select multiple class="filter filter-open">
            <option>option1</option>
            <option>option2</option>
            <option>option3</option>        
            <option>option4</option>  
            <option>option5</option>  
          </select>
        </span>
        </i>
      </span>
    </th>
    <th>third</th>
  </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
  <tr>
    <td>XXXXX XXXXXX XXXXXXXXXX XXXXXXXXXXXXXX</td>
    <td>YYYYY YYYYYY YYYYYYYYYY YYYYYYYYYYYYYY</td>
    <td>ZZZZZ ZZZZZZ ZZZZZZZZZZ ZZZZZZZZZZZZZZ</td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>000000 00000000 0000000000 00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000</td>
  <td>1111111 11111 11111 111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111 </td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>000000 00000000 0000000000 00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000</td>
  <td>1111111 11111 11111 111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111 </td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>

</body>
```

Comment: The downside is that `th` can overflow. On a real life scenario, table columns are resizable and user could resize a column narrower than the text on the `th`.